# calling Dll with another Dll in C++

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I have a DLL that I want to call from within another DLL. I made a C++ MFC DLL with this code:

```
    extern "C" INT PASCAL EXPORT Locale()
    {

        AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
        typedef BOOL(WINAPI* LPFNDLLGetStringLabel)( CWnd *, int, LPTSTR , CWinApp *, LPSTR , LPCTSTR );
        int bRes = 0; //false;
        char achEvent[ 250 ];
        HINSTANCE hDLL;   

        hDLL = LoadLibrary( L"C:\\1.dll" );
        if ( hDLL != NULL )
        {
            CString ocStrInfo;
            ocStrInfo += "Alfa";
            ocStrInfo += ";";
            ocStrInfo += "Alfa";
            ocStrInfo += ";";
            ocStrInfo += "Alfa";

                LPFNDLLGetStringLabel lpfnDllFunc;
                lpfnDllFunc = (LPFNDLLGetStringLabel)GetProcAddress( hDLL, "GetStringLabel");

                if ( lpfnDllFunc )
                    if( lpfnDllFunc( NULL, 111, (LPTSTR)ocStrInfo.GetBuffer(), AfxGetApp(), achEvent, NULL )) {
                        return bRes=1;
                    }else{
                        return bRes=0;
                    }

            FreeLibrary( hDLL );
    }
   }
```

The following code is calling the second DLL, but it isn't working right:

```
int main(){
HINSTANCE dllHandle = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\2.dll");
if(dllHandle == NULL ){
    std::cout << "alarm";
}
typedef int(*Locale)(void);
FARPROC pTest = GetProcAddress(HMODULE (dllHandle),"Locale");
if(pTest == NULL ){
    std::cout << "alarm";
}
Locale con = Locale(pTest);
int r= 1; 
r =con();
cout << r;
FreeLibrary(dllHandle);
getchar();
return 0;
```

}

But dllhandle equal with null... can anybody help me?

Comment: Why can't you call the second DLL in the same way that you called the first DLL? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Check GetLastError after calling LoadLibrary. One possible reason may be different Dll bitness, for example, trying to load 32-bit Dll to 64-bit process.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Using this tool in *profile mode* will show you whether the dependencies between your binaries (EXE - DLL1 - DLL2) can be resolved at runtime.

One reason might be: DLL1 cannot be started because DLL2 has not been found.

You should also take a look that the way you export Locale (extern "C" INT PASCAL EXPORT) is correct!

As already mentioned, you should also have a look at GetLastError.

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting library dependencies in windows you could monitor your program with procmon. See (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)